Did a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04 on HP Elitebook 8440p i7 and now getting random freeze ups
It seems the freeze ups happen during file access either through Files access on the desktop with no other programs running or through other running programs. I can have a browser (ie Chromium) running for days no problems, but if I try to download and save a file or rename it for saving it randomly freezes and hard reset only way out. I've tried reinstalling gnome and changing screen resolution but didn't help. Again, it seems to be caused by file manipulation/access.
Earlier versions of Ubuntu ran rock solid no problems on this same hardware.
Any thoughts or suggestions?

Decided to try Nemo file manager, installed it and so far everything works as it should. Nautilus (I learned the name of the default Gnome file manager!), if I use it, still causes freeze ups. And I'm liking Nemo so far.
